# Where are my Drupal E-Mail settings?

Tags: email, drupal, dashboard

Shame on me. :(

I forgot where I configured the E-Mail account used in my Drupal site.
I guess I set up the E-Mail with the installation of Drupal, could that be possible?
Does Drupal care about registering the E-Mail address and getting incoming mails?

I get all the mails at this address forwarded to my private E-Mail address, but I really don't know where I registerd the drupal address and where I told Drupal to forward mails to my private address.

In the Drupal dashboard I can't find settings for an E-Mail Account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal 6 site email is stored at 'Site Configuration' -> 'Site information' (admin/settings/site-information).

Drupal 7 is stored at 'Configuration' -> 'Site Information' (admin/config/system/site-information).

Drupal does not handle receiving emails or forwarding emails. This setting sets the from address for most generic site emails (new account, forgot password, etc). You must have configured the forwarding through your mail hosting provider.

Comment: I had different logins for my Confixx Panel. I only looked at the Login with just very few settings. The main login had everything as aspected. So I began to wonder.